# Constant for loop yields wrong result

Tags: c, for-loop, cuda

I am about to write a histogram kernel for CUDA devices. It's based on [NVIDIA's paper](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_64_website/projects/histogram256/doc/histogram.pdf).

The idea is that every thread calculates a partial histogram of a certain part (in my case of a volume) and writes it to a block of shared memory. However, I encountered a weird problem with the algorithm and stripped down the kernel to the significant parts:

```
__global__ void calcHist64()
{
    extern __shared__ unsigned char partialHistograms[];

    //a unique sequential thread id within this block, used to determine the memory in which to write the partial histogram
    unsigned int seqTid = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x;       
#pragma unroll
    for(int i = 0; i < 255; ++i)
    {
        //increment the thread's partial histogram value
        partialHistograms[seqTid]++; 
    }
    //each partial histogram should now be 255
    //Output the value for every thread in a certain block
    if(blockIdx.x == 0 && blockIdx.y == 31)
        printf("Partial[%i][%i]: %i\n", threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y, partialHistograms[partialHistRoot]);  
}
```

The kernel is invoked via:

```
int sharedMemory = 4096;
dim blocks(32, 32, 1);
dim3 threadsPerBlock(8,8,1);
calcHist64<<<blocks, threadsPerBlock, sharedMemory>>>();
```

I expect each partial histogram to have a value of 255. However, this is only true for the first few blocks (low `blockIdx.x` / `blockIdx.y`). The values for the other blocks vary heavily. The last blocks (`blockIdx.y == 31`) have values of 239 or 240.

I can't explain this behavior. It is a constant for loop which runs exactly 255 times after all. Each thread accesses different parts of shared memory so there should be no race conditions.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: I don't know if this is the case, but maybe it is some issue with different processor cores holding old values in their cache. The last one to flush cache to memory may have old values for some of the blocks in `partialHistograms` - and it explains why the last blocks are affected (first blocks have been with 255 for so long that it was already propagated to every cache). Have you tried using mutexes or something like that inside the `for` loop? I can't think of any other issue with this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not initializing the shared memory.  It is not automatically initialized to zero for you.

After this line of code:

```
unsigned int seqTid = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x;
```

Add this:

```
partialHistograms[seqTid] = 0;
```

Also in your code you don't define `partialHistRoot`.   I am assuming that `partialHistRoot` == `seqTid`.  If this is not the case then you have a race condition and your statement

> Each thread accesses different parts of shared memory so there should be no race conditions.

is not correct.

Comment: Ah, of course. Stupid mistake. It just did seem to work without an initialization. That's why I forgot it. `partialHistRoot` shouldn't be there any more in the question. It's equal to `seqTid`.